# PyQt5: How to get/set properties using QtDBus

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, dbus, qtdbus

I'm trying to communicate with SMPlayer using its D-Bus interface "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2". Calling methods works fine. For example:

```
smp = QDBusInterface(r'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.smplayer', "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2", "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player")
smp.call("Pause")
smp.call("Seek",QDBusArgument(int(value_in_ms)*1000, QMetaType.LongLong))
```

I tried both of these variants below I found online, but the result is `None` for the first variant (this how I think it should be done), and I get the error `No such method 'Rate' in interface 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player' at object path '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2'(signature '')` for the second one:

```
res = smp.property("Rate")
res = smp.call("Rate")
```

I verified that the these properties actually exist. I can read them using dbus-send or qdbus on the command-line. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. You're using the wrong interface to get/set the properties, and the argument types are specified incorrectly. Also, you are trying to use `property()`, which is an inherited [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#property) method with no relevance to dbus.

The interactive demo script below shows how to get and set the SMPLayer Rate property (the format of which is [documented here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mpris-spec/2.2/Player_Interface.html#Simple-Type:Playback_Rate)). Note that it is essential that [QDBusVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdbusvariant.html) is used to specify the value when setting the property:

```
from PyQt5 import QtDBus

service = 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.smplayer'
path = '/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2'
iface = 'org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player'
props = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'

smp = QtDBus.QDBusInterface(service, path, props)
msg = smp.call('Get', iface, 'Rate')
print(f'Current Rate: {msg.arguments()[0]}\n')

rate = input('Enter New Rate: ')

try:
    rate = float(rate)
except ValueError:
    print(f'ERROR: invalid rate value: {rate!r}')
else:
    msg = smp.call('Set', iface, 'Rate', QtDBus.QDBusVariant(rate))
    if msg.errorName():
        print('ERROR:', msg.errorMessage())
    else:
        msg = smp.call('Get', iface, 'Rate')
        print(f'Set New Rate: {msg.arguments()[0]}')
```

Output:

```
$ python demo.py
Current Rate: 1.0

Enter New Rate: 1.25
Set New Rate: 1.25
```

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't realized I need two Interfaces, one for Methods and one for properties, but now it works perfect!